# Как получить ответ от сервера в байтах?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно отправить на определенный сервер запрос в байтах и получить ответ от сервера. Как это сделать?

```
    public static bool IsListening(string server, int port)
    {
        using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] message =
                {
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
                };
                tcpClient.Connect(server, port);
                NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                networkStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Сразу после networkStream.Write(...):

```
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int numBytesRead=0;
            while ((numBytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
            }
           byte[] readed = ms.ToArray();
           //делайте что нужно с полученными байтами

        }
```

Comment: Выбрасывает исключение на строку с while.

Comment: Какое исключение?

Comment: `System.IO.IOException: Не удается прочитать данные из транспортного соединения: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
   в System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   в System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
   в System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)`

Comment: А Вы уверены что сервер посылает Вам что-то обратно?

Comment: Да, должен. 1/5 ip работает, но подключается ко всем.

Comment: Подключается, это значит что на той стороне кто-то слушает, однако это не гарантирует, что сервер отсылает что-либо обратно.

Comment: Отсылает, т.к. подобный запрос на golang работает